# Adding list position items into dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

--UPDATED--

I'm having difficulty trying to add list items into a dictionary as keyerror: 0 keeps appearing. This is the error that keeps popping up:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-8a7b96769ff1> in <module>
      4     # create a dictionary for each document in the master list
      5     document_dict = {}
----> 6     document_dict['cik_number'] = document[0]
      7     document_dict['company_name'] = document[1]
      8     document_dict['form_id'] = document[2]

KeyError: 0
```

This is the code I currently have:

> ```
> for index, document in enumerate(master_data):
>
>    document_dict = {}
>    document_dict['cik_number'] = document[0]
>    document_dict['company_name'] = document[1]
>    document_dict['form_id'] = document[2]
>    document_dict['date'] = document[3]
>    document_dict['file_url'] = document[4]
>
>    master_data[index] = document_dict
> ```

I am trying to add the following items respectively into the dictionary groups. The end result I want to get is something like this:
E.g.

```
{'cik_number':['1236397','1236458'...], 'company_name':['BRADBURY DANIEL','WILLIAMS PAUL S'...], 'form_id':['4','4','10-K'...], 'date': ['20190401','20190401'...], 'file_url':['https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1236397/0000886744-19-000047.txt'...]}
```

This is the data set I am trying to append into the dictionary. So basically, I am envisioning 5 keys in the dictionary: cik_num, company_name, form_id, date, file_url. The data in this dataset should fall into its respective dictionary keys.

```
[['1236397', 'BRADBURY DANIEL', '4', '20190401', 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1236397/0000886744-19-000047.txt'], ['1236458', 'WILLIAMS PAUL S', '4', '20190401', 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1236458/0001227654-19-000074.txt'], ['1237789', 'BLAIR DONALD W', '4', '20190401', 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1237789/0001127602-19-013788.txt'], ['1237831', 'GLOBUS MEDICAL INC', '4', '20190401', 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1237831/0001209191-19-022014.txt'], ['1238028', 'TALOR EYAL', '4', '20190401', 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1238028/0001236031-19-000004.txt'], ['1238885', 'CHAPMAN STEVEN M', '4', '20190401', 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1238885/0001225208-19-005929.txt'], ['1238978', 'HENDRICKSON THOMAS', '4', '20190401', 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1238978/0001140361-19-006195.txt'], ['1239188', 'GENERAL STEEL HOLDINGS INC', '10-K', '20190401', 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1239188/0001144204-19-017485.txt'], ['1239786', 'FRISSORA MARK P', '4', '20190401', 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1239786/0000858339-19-000093.txt']]
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this? Please help :)

Comment: The error means a ``document`` is empty (or at least has no item at ``0``); It also means that ``document`` is a ``dict`` (due to a ``KeyError`` instead of an ``IndexError``). Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] for this.

Comment: Besides the errors, your data `document` does not look right. Is that should be list of lists?  Double check it first.

Answer (score 0):

JohnthanYong, can you take a look and see if that's what you want:

#### Updated:

(after your new post) basically, just get all relevant info. and group them together before put into the final dictionary.

```
from pprint import pprint 
doc_dict =  dict()
click_numbers, company_names = [], []
form_ids, dates, urls = [], [], []

for record in master_data:
    click_numbers.append(record[0])
    company_names.append(record[1])
    form_ids.append(record[2])
    dates.append(record[3])
    urls.append(record[4])

doc_dict['click_num']  = click_numbers
doc_dict['company_name'] = company_names
doc_dict['form_id']  = form_ids
doc_dict['date'] = dates
doc_dict['url'] = urls 

pprint(doc_dict)
```

Outputs:  (skip some... it's too long)

```
{'click_num': ['1236397',
               '1236458',
               '1237789',
               '1237831',
               '1238028',
               '1238885',
               '1238978',
               '1239188',
               '1239786'],
 'company_name': ['BRADBURY DANIEL',
                  'WILLIAMS PAUL S',
                  'BLAIR DONALD W',
                  'GLOBUS MEDICAL INC',
                  'TALOR EYAL',
                  'CHAPMAN STEVEN M',
                  'HENDRICKSON THOMAS',
                  'GENERAL STEEL HOLDINGS INC',
                  'FRISSORA MARK P'], .......
```

Comment: Thanks for the go. I have updated my question, hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: Hi, can you try to see the `Updated` post will give you what you want after your `updated`?